# Why does a VBA macro that opens another workbook not work when callend from dot.net

Tags: .net, excel, vba, excel-interop, blueprism

When working in BluePrism, I have a problem running an Excel macro that opens another workbook.

### The Excel-VBA routine

I have a `Sub` in a macro enabled excel workbook `\\myCompany\myFolder\myMasterbook.xlsm` that opens another workbook

```
Public Sub OpenMyFile(Optional book2open As String = "")
    Dim openedBook As Workbook
    Debug.Print "About to open", book2open

    Set openedBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(book2open)
    If openedBook Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Could not open it"
    Else
        Debug.Print "I found", openedBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
        ' Actually, I do a lot more with that workbook, of course
        openedBook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

When, in the Immidiate window (which you open with `Ctrl-G`), I enter

```
call OpenMyFile ("\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx")
```

I see the workbook open and close and get the response in the Immediate window

```
About to open   \\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx
I found   Cell A1 content
```

### Calling the VBA from BluePrism

In a Robotic Automation Process (RPA), using BluePrism, I need to open the workbook that contains this VBA `Sub` and run it.
In the Immidiate window, I now get

```
About to open   \\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx
Could not open it
```

I tried two things to resolve it

#### Call without arguments

If I define my `Sub` in VBA as

```
Public Sub OpenMyFile(Optional book2open As String = "\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx")
```

and call it with `OpenMyFile`, but that does not resolve my problem, as I **need** to pass `book2open` to VBA.

#### Make the parameter mandatory

If I define my `Sub` in VBA as `Public Sub OpenMyFile(book2open As String')`, I get this error: `Internal : Could not execute code stage because exception thrown by code stage: Cannot run the macro

'OpenMyFile("C:\Users\P01549\Documents\TestHorsten.xlsx", -1)'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`

### The `MS Excel VBO - Extended` object uses interop

Part of the dot.net code can be found in BluePrisms *Object Studio*. I run the following "Actions" of this object

#### Create Instance

```
Dim excel as Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Create a GUID with which we can kill the instance later
' if we have to play hardball to get rid of it.
excel.Caption = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()

handle = GetHandle(excel)
```

#### Open Workbook

```
Dim wb as Object = GetInstance(handle).Workbooks.Open(filename)
name = wb.Name
wb.Activate()
```

With

- `handle` : the handle returned by Create Instance
- `filename` : `\\myCompany\myFolder\myMasterbook.xlsm`

#### Run Macro

```
GetInstance(Handle).Run(Macro_Name)
```

With

- `handle` : the handle returned by Create Instance
- `Macro_Name` : `OpenMyFile("\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx")`

Does anyone have an explanation or a workacound?

Comment: Set openedBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(book2open)
When you are running this from C#, what is the application object? Do you think it can open a workbook?

Comment: It is the Excel application, and it obviously can, because it does so when called from the imediate window

Comment: So, pretty much, the BluePrism is not relevant to the question? E.g. the question could be **how to call the "macro" from C#**? It really seems interesting, thus you may consider edititng it a bit and provide some [mcve] of how/what you tried in a C# console application? Furthermore, you may make your "macro" to just one robust line `MsgBox "Something"` to make sure you can access it from C#.

Comment: Most probably.That is why it is not in the title.

Comment: The immediate window in the visual basic window in excel? When you have the excel application running? But you are calling your macro from BluePrism via MS Excel VBO - Extended - So is there an instance of Excel running at that point? or is the running application some sort of vb hosting app? Does BluePrism launch Excel?

Comment: Ineed, I first instantiate Excel from BluePrism, then open the macro enabled workbook. (Actually I open a macro enabled template.) All this runs some snippets of C# code, including the `GetInstance(Handle).Run(Macro_Name)`

Comment: Can you not open the workbook directly from Blue Prism? why do you need to open a workbook that opens another workbook?. Also, whats the value of `book2open` when it attempts to open from Blue Prism?

Comment: I have to call that VBA Sub because it not only copies data from the source, it also validates and preprocesses it.

Comment: The problem may be with your Macro_Name input format. If you want to pass path as string parameter within macro name string parameter, then it should look like this: "OpenMyFile(""\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx"")".

Comment: Indeed, you have to write `"OpenMyFile(""\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx"")"` to pass `OpenMyFile("\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx")`. That is what I do.

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work, however you can try some workaround to provide the path. Instead of passing the path through sub parameter, pass it to Excel file with macro (for example to 1st cell of 1st sheet) using Set Cell Value action, then get path from cell in the macro (book2open = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value) and use it to open the target Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually the case that Application.Run takes parameters to functions as separate arguments:

This argument is not appropriate for Application.Run:
`OpenMyFile("\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx")`

You can try to amend the VBO to have a run parameter with arguments:
Write another code stage called 'Run Macro With Parameter' (or whatever you want to call it)

`GetInstance(Handle).Run(Macro_Name, param1)`

where Macro_Name is "OpenMyFile", and param1 is "\\myCompany\myFolder\myWorkbook.xlsx"